# Compactness and metric space

Tags: metric-spaces, compactness

i know that if A and B are compact then there exists $(a,b)\in A\times B, d(a,b) = d(A,B)$ I want to find an example where this is not true if A is compact and B closed

I put $A=[1,2]$ and $B=]-\infty,0[ $ in $\mathbb{R}^*=]-\infty,0[\cup ]0,+\infty[$

is it correct ?

here B is closed but not bounded then it is not compact right?

and d(A,B)=1 but d(a,b)>1

is it true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. In fact, you could have taken $B=[-1,0[$. While it is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$, it is closed in your $\mathbb{R}^*$.

Comment: but it is compact no? @sambo?

Comment: @PolineSandra $B$ is closed (and bounded), but not compact. If both $A$ and $B$ were compact, the points $a\in A$, $b\in B$ with $d(a,b)=d(A,B)$ would exist.

Comment: how to prove that is not compact  please?

Comment: @PolineSandra There is no finite subcover of the open cover by $U_n=\left]-\infty,-\frac1n\right[$, $n\in\Bbb N$

Comment: @Poline Another proof would be that $[-1,0[$ is *not* closed as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$; subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual topology) are compact if and only if they are closed and bounded (*in* $\mathbb{R}$).